# Using an if statement with a while loop?

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to do this question:

Design a program that reads in a list of numbers terminated by -9999 and prints out the sum entered.

I am amending the program so that only values between `1` and `100` are summed, and as you can see I've tried to implement an `if` statement. But, nothing has changed and this part has stumped me. I've been stuck on it for ages, code follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Summing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Number, Sum = 0;

        System.out.println("Enter a list of whole numbers, finished by -9999");
        Number = sc.nextInt();

        if (Number > 0 || Number < 100);
        while (Number != -9999) {
            Sum = Sum + Number;
            Number = sc.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("Sum is " + Sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move the `if` statement inside of the loop.  Right now the `if` statement is only being executed **once** before entering the loop (and it is doing nothing, thanks to the `;` immediately following the condition).  You want it to be used on every value.

Also notice I changed the `||` to an `&&`. Otherwise for example 101 would match, which is not between 0 and 100. Finally, `a = a + b` can always be written more succinctly as `a += b`.

```
while (Number != -9999) {
    if (Number > 0 && Number < 100) {
        Sum += Number;
    }
    Number = sc.nextInt();
}
```

As another stylistic change (which is pretty much universal convention) you should consider changing your variables to lowercase names.

Answer (score 1):

You placed the `if` before the `while` loop,
and it has an empty (= does nothing at all).
The condition was also wrong anyway as `Number > 0 || Number < 100` will match *all* numbers. You want to change the `||` to `&&`.

This should work:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Number, Sum = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter a list of whole numbers, finished by -9999");
    Number = sc.nextInt();

    while (Number != -9999) {
        if (1 < Number && Number < 100) {    
            Sum += Number;
        }
        Number = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("Sum is " + Sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You were fairly close, but the if test should be in the loop (and you should probably use `{` and `}` braces). By convention Java variable names start with a lower case letter, and I would prefer the `+=` operator for adding to the `sum`. Also, to check your range you logically need an and (not an or). Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a list of whole numbers, finished by -9999");
    int number = sc.nextInt();
    int sum = 0;
    while (number != -9999) {
        if (number > 0 && number < 100) {
            sum += number;
        }
        number = sc.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("Sum is " + sum);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your if is BEFORE the while loop. Put it IN the loop.